# error al subir cambios del proyecto a git por la carpeta node_modules

Tags: angular, github, git-push

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en a parte final de la imagen me esta mostrando este error ya que no me quiere permitir subir la carpeta de modules que podria hacer?ya intente borrarla del front del proyecto de angular pero practicamente es indespiensable ya que si la borro me generara error en todo el proyecto

Comment: ¿De dónde sacas que el error se debe  al directorio node_modules? Según lo que te indica el mensaje el problema es que en el repositorio hay cambios que no están en local y te sugiere primero hacer `git pull` para descargar esos cambios y luego de eso podrías hacer `git push`.

Answer (score 1):

En el repositorio debes agregar el archivo .gitignore con la configuracion para angular, el cual ignore la carpeta de node_modules:

Te recomiendo que le hagas pool luego de haber agregado el archivo y reintenta.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/master/.gitignore

```
/dist/
/bazel-out
/integration/bazel/bazel-*
*.log
node_modules

# Include when developing application packages.
pubspec.lock
.c9
.idea/
.devcontainer/*
!.devcontainer/README.md
!.devcontainer/recommended-devcontainer.json
!.devcontainer/recommended-Dockerfile
.settings/
.vscode/launch.json
.vscode/settings.json
.vscode/tasks.json
*.swo
*.swp
modules/.settings
modules/.vscode
.vimrc
.nvimrc

# Don't check in secret files
*secret.js

# Ignore npm/yarn debug log
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

# build-analytics
.build-analytics

# rollup-test output
/modules/rollup-test/dist/

# User specific bazel settings
.bazelrc.user

# User specific ng-dev settings
.ng-dev.user*

.notes.md
baseline.json

# Ignore .history for the xyz.local-history VSCode extension
.history

# Husky
.husky/_
```